# g cloud run application deploy service is down 503 error

Tags: java, gcloud, spring-boot-actuator

currently im testing my application on gcloud so i deployed container on gcloud run : https://flight-api-j4zdo6q6xq-uc.a.run.app/actuator/health

and my response is :

```
{
   "status":"DOWN",
   "components":{
      "diskSpace":{
         "status":"DOWN",
         "details":{
            "total":0,
            "free":0,
            "threshold":10485760,
            "exists":true
         }
      },
      "ping":{
         "status":"UP"
      }
   }
}
```

there are some logs:

[image]

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always

endpoints:
  health:
    sensitive: false
```

and this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:7.4.1-jdk17-alpine AS TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle $APP_HOME

COPY gradle $APP_HOME/gradle
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
USER root
RUN chown -R gradle /home/gradle/src

RUN gradle build || return 0
COPY . .
RUN gradle clean build
FROM openjdk:17
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=FlightApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/

WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME .

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar ${ARTIFACT_NAME}
```

Is someone more familiar with gcloud ? What issues can be there, locally ofcourse it's kind of working maybe is there some issues with deployed container propertises. I appraciate for any ideas, thanks, have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

So i added new property to application.yaml :

```
management:
  health:
    diskspace:
      enabled: false
```

worked for me